# How to change the text of a specific cell when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

```
<tr>
<div id=tableHead>
<th>Poster</th>
<th style="padding-left: 70px;">Destination</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px;">Takeoff time</th>
<th style="padding-left: 10px; "># of passenger</th>
<th style="padding-left: 35px; ">Post time</th> 
</div>
</tr>


<?php session_start() ; 
    include 'databaseConnection.php' ;
    $sqlCommand3 = "SELECT * FROM posts ;" ;
            $result3 = mysqli_query($conn , $sqlCommand3);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;"> <?php echo $row['poster']; ?></td>
            <td style="padding-left: 45px;"><?php echo $row['post_destination']; ?></td>
            <td style="padding-left: 30px;"><?php echo $row['post_readyTime']; ?></td>

            <td style="padding-left: 45px;"> <?php  echo $row['post_numberOfPassenger'];   


            ?></td>
            <td style="padding-left: 32px;"><?php echo $row['post_submitTime']; ?></td>


            <td id=joinRow>
                <a href="riderPage.php?edit=<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>" class="edit_btn " id = "<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>">Join</a>

            </td>



            <td>
                <a href="riderPage.php?del=<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>" class="del_btn" id="<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>">Delete</a>

            </td>

        </tr>
    <?php } ?>



</table>

<script>

var x = document.getElementsByClassName('edit_btn');

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].addEventListener("click" , function(){
    x[i].innerHTML = "Joined";
});
    }
</script>
```

I would like to change the text of "join" to "joined" (of a specific cell) whenever that "join" (of that specific cell) is clicked. Here is my source code but it's not working. What's wrong with this chunk of code? How to solve it? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: because onclick you are redirecting to riderPage.php page

Comment: you need to add preventDefault

Comment: and try to post a HTML/CSS code with PHP so we can test it

Comment: <td id=joinRow> to <td id="joinRow">

Comment: Should not set the same `id to all tags...

Comment: use object "this"